# Simplest way to get a value from a select row in a table and send it to a bounded task flow

Tags: oracle-adf

I'm trying to select a row in a displayed table and use a value in the row as input to a bounded task flow.  This seems like a very common thing to do so you can reuse task flows, but everything I have found on the web requires tons of code.  The missing piece seems to be getting the data from a select row to the input of the task flow.  Are there any good examples of this on the web?  I must be searching for the wrong thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- First get the value from selected row with this simple way :

a- add column in your table and add command button / link with PropertyActionListener to set the selected value in pageFlowScope as follows :

```
<af:column id="c8" headerText="Select">
                      <af:commandLink text="Select" id="cl1">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{pageFlowScope.testVal}"
                                                     value="#{row.FirstName}"/>
                      </af:commandLink>
                    </af:column>
```

b- In Taskflow properties > in parameters section > add your param with the selection value from pageFlowScope variable ... in our case will be #{pageFlowScope.testVal}

Comment: Thanks!  That's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

While A_BOSS is correct, you can use setPropertyListener to set the value, unfortunately, the example is flawed. The example is using a memory scoped parameter: pageFlowScope.testVal. is is very bad practice to do this in ADF and should *never* be done in production, There are myriad issues do ing this. For example: JDeveloper cannot give feedback if you spell the param wrong and it is prone to NPE. While it is not exactly an anti-pattern, it's close enough not to do it.  Proper way to do it is to create and register a managed bean and pass that bean's attribute: pageFLowScope.bean.testal

Comment: Thanks for the info, this was the approach I originally took but it seemed like a lot of code for something so simple.  I will probably use a bean for production.

Comment: It is prefered to use a transient attribute in a VO over a bean parameter where possible.  Beans are a second choice where transient attributes are not possible. With transient attribute, no bean, no registration and no memory scope issues.